# I have only one primary key in my Django Model, but it shows error as multiple primary key

Tags: python, django, heroku

My model is

```
class authenticate(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    uid=models.CharField(max_length=39,editable=False)
    image=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    mobile=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    dob=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    regno=models.CharField(max_length=10,editable=False)
    created=models.CharField(max_length=10,editable=False)
    last_login=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=5)
    admin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Error occurred when tried to migrate my model in Heroku repo:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTableDefinition: multiple primary keys for table "Auth_authenticate" are not allowed


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

--
--
--
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple primary keys for table "Auth_authenticate" are not allowed
```

The above model is working perfectly when I am using sqlite DB.

Comment: try : `email=models.ForeignKey()` then `makemigrate` and `migrate` command

Comment: still the same error @YeganehSalami

Comment: can you rename your class? maybe you have conflict with the table's name of `Auth` module

Comment: If you don’t specify primary_key=True for any field in your model, Django will automatically add an AutoField to hold the primary key, so you don’t need to set primary_key=True on any of your fields unless you want to override the default primary-key behaviour.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244862/multiple-primary-keys-for-table-app-employee-are-not-allowed

Comment: try to migrate from the beginning

Comment: I added primary_key=False in ever fields and still getting the same error @YeganehSalami

Comment: you have to migrate from the beginnig. it means that recreate your table

Comment: and how shall I do that? @YeganehSalami

Comment: empty your migrate folder except init file. delete your table. and `makemigrate` and `migrate` . your migrate steps should look like the link above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, Django gives each model the following field:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.

the reason it show multiple primary key is maybe you have added multiple primary key and its exsits on migration file.

Solution 1.
delete your tables (or schema) and migration files then re-migrate.

Solution 2.
open your migration file look for table that have multiple primary key then delete one and migrate

Comment: Django doesn't add the id field if you specify primary_key on another field.

Comment: ERRORS:
Auth.authenticate.id: (fields.E100) AutoFields must set primary_key=True.

Comment: You should clear your migration file for that app and run your make migration command again

Comment: @NaqibHakimi I am pushing my codes to Heroku App and migrating it there.